# How to get URL string in java code, from a CUSTOM PROTOCOL URL in MAC OS X application

Tags: java, macos, swt, protocols

I am developing an application in java for mac osx. I need to implement a custom protocol for it. Its same as some inbuilt application in osx, like when we hit `mailto://` in `Safari` browser it open default mail application. 
My requirement is same as it. I have written following code in `info.plist` of application bundle and its working fine.

```
 <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>SBR</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
          <string>sbr</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
```

I can open my application using `Safari` browser by hitting  `sbr://`.

**Problem**-
I want to pass some argument with this protocol like `sbr://user:pass@abc.xyz.com` and then take these arguments `user:pass@abc.xyz.com` as `String` in java code to perform some operation.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution to your problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31694986/382877

It worked for me. I was using MacOS X 10.8.2