# How can we configure the install4j executable to take query parameters provided in the custom uri to take as arguments to pass to the main app

Tags: install4j

We have defined custom uri scheme for our Mac OS X using install4j but couldn't find a way to pass query parameters to the app as arguments using custom uri so that those are being passed to the underlying main method as arguments for us to process.

Example :

customuri://?somekey=value

when opened in a browser the app opens up with the parameters to be processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The application has to be registered to handle the URL invocation.

This is not related to install4j.

See

[Handle custom URL schemes in an OS X Java application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074610/handle-custom-url-schemes-in-an-os-x-java-application)

Comment: Thanks Ingo. We have already done that custom XML fragment definition in install4j to register the custom URI. But what i was looking at is how do we pass query parameters so that those are passed to the underlying main method mentioned in the install4j installable. Since install4j generated the installable i am not sure how do we handle the custom URI parameters? Any suggestions? Can we write custom native App and embed it together with the install4j generated file?

Comment: You have to write a JNI library that registers the application for handling URL application like outlined in the referenced question.